# Moving images automatically in circular path in html, css and js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Moving images(7-images) automatically in circular path in html, css and js and also each image(size would be bigger than initial stage) will be show in center like a popup(having Image and three buttons) and again rotate all images and then next image will shown in center in popup(having Image and three buttons)and so on, Such that user can click on that button to open link.

```
  <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
            <style>
    .circle-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 5em auto 0;
      /*border: solid 5px tomato;*/
    }
    .circle-container > * {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      margin: -3em;
      width: 200px;
      height: auto;
    }
    .circle-container > *:nth-of-type(1) {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(10em) rotate(0deg);
              transform: rotate(0deg) translate(10em) rotate(0deg);
    }
    .circle-container > *:nth-of-type(2) {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(51.42deg) translate(10em) rotate(-51.42deg);
              transform: rotate(51.42deg) translate(10em) rotate(-51.42deg);
    }
    .circle-container > *:nth-of-type(3) {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(102.84deg) translate(10em) rotate(-102.84deg);
              transform: rotate(102.84deg) translate(10em) rotate(-102.84deg);
    }
    .circle-container > *:nth-of-type(4) {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(154.26deg) translate(10em) rotate(-154.26deg);
              transform: rotate(154.26deg) translate(10em) rotate(-154.26deg);
    }
    .circle-container > *:nth-of-type(5) {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(205.68deg) translate(10em) rotate(-205.68deg);
              transform: rotate(205.68deg) translate(10em) rotate(-205.68deg);
    }
    .circle-container > *:nth-of-type(6) {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(257.1deg) translate(10em) rotate(-257.1deg);
              transform: rotate(257.1deg) translate(10em) rotate(-257.1deg);
    }
    .circle-container > *:nth-of-type(7) {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(308.52deg) translate(10em) rotate(-308.52deg);
              transform: rotate(308.52deg) translate(10em) rotate(-308.52deg);
    }
    .circle-container img {
      display: block;
      width: 100px;  
      max-width: 100px;
      height: 80px;  
      max-height: 80px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
       filter: grayscale(100%);
      border: solid 5px tomato;
      -webkit-transition: .15s;
      transition: .15s;
    }
    /*img{
        margin: 5em;
    }*/
    .circle-container img:hover {
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
              filter: grayscale(0);
    }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <ul class='circle-container'> 
              <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature'></li> 
              <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract'></li> 
              <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats'></li> 
              <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food'></li>  
              <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals'></li> 
              <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/business'></li> 
              <li><img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people'></li>
          </ul>            
        </body>
```

[See attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSTV9.png)

Comment: on which part are you stuck ? pls edit https://jsfiddle.net/24nrkmmb/

Comment: I want to just rotate these images automatically. By click on each image, a Popup will  open with three buttons in it(Image would be larger in popup so user can see it clearly.).  I already attached pic for the same. I'm beginner in JS, JQuery and Java Script.

Comment: you did not write one line of javascript and expect that somone writes your code? and you would properly not understand the code ? I'm voting to close this question because there was no effort

Comment: The Image which you seen in attachment was in two parts and second one is designed in "PAINT" , After that i attached both the pic, and i don't have any code of JAVASCRIPT or JS or JQuery. If you can do what i need then please edit the " jsfiddle". Otherwise OK.